# A timer calling a web service in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, timer

I have a website (written in C# ASP.Net) that will collect some data and has some users.

I want a Timer thing on the server that will run automatically at a certain time without supervision or any active sessions. This timer will then call a WCF service that will send some emails to users. (for example once in a day)

Note that I have a website hosting and I don't have access to server to write windows application.
Also I have tried Global.asax with a timer in it which didn't work.

Comment: Look into [cron services](http://www.cronjobservices.com/)

Comment: Any way to manage it over my own server? You know there are some security issues with these cron services!

Comment: BTW Thank you very much that was what I've asked for.